# Remove (child) node from XML DOM object using VBA (Excel)

Tags: excel, xml, vba, removechild

I am creating quite complex XML files using a template, replacing special search strings with values which can be entered in an Excel sheet, and then storing the xml-file.

```
 Dim strInpPath As String
 Dim strOutpPath As String
 
 Dim fso
 Dim f
 Dim oDomRd As Object, oNode As Object, i As Long, oAtt As Object, oGroup As Object, oDomWr As Object
 Dim oTest As Object
 
 
 strInpPath = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 4).Value
 strOutputPath = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 4).Value
 

 Set oDomRd = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
 oDomRd.Load strInpPath
 Set oDomWr = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
 
 Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(strOutputPath, 2, True)

 Set oGroup = oDomRd.SelectNodes("/")
 Set oNode = oGroup.NextNode
 If Not (oNode Is Nothing) Then
    strout = oNode.XML
    strout = ScanTable("_S_AND_R_TABLE_1", strout)
    oDomRd.LoadXML (strout)
    Set oGroup = oDomRd.SelectNodes("/")
    Set oNode = oGroup.NextNode
    
    If oNode.HasChildNodes() Then
        Set oLists = oNode.DocumentElement
        Run RemoveOptionalEmptyTags(oLists)
    End If
    strout = oNode.XML
    f.write (strout)
 Else
     strout = "001 error reading file"
 End If
 MsgBox strout
 
End Function
```

Some of the field values are not mandatory so they can be left empty. In this case, the first procedure (scantable) enters "##REMOVE##" as value. In the second step, I want to step through the entire DOMObject and remove the nodes having the value "##REMOVE##"

for this second step I created a procedure:

```
Public Function RemoveOptionalEmptyTags(ByRef oLists)

    For Each listnode In oLists.ChildNodes
        If listnode.HasChildNodes() Then
            Run RemoveOptionalEmptyTags(listnode) 
        Else
            lcBasename = listnode.ParentNode.BaseName
            lcText = listnode.Text
            If lcText = "##REMOVE##" Then
                listnode.ParentNode.RemoveChild listnode
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next listnode

End Function
```

This works pretty fine, the only problem is, that the node is not **removed**, it only is empty ():

```
    <Cdtr>
        <Nm>Name Creditor</Nm>
        <PstlAdr>
            <Ctry>DE</Ctry>
            <AdrLine>Street</AdrLine>
            <AdrLine/>
        </PstlAdr>
    </Cdtr>
```

now the question:
How can I completely REMOVE the node, so it would look like this (the second  is gone):

```
    <Cdtr>
        <Nm>Name Creditor</Nm>
        <PstlAdr>
            <Ctry>DE</Ctry>
            <AdrLine>Street</AdrLine>
        </PstlAdr>
    </Cdtr>
```

Comment: How do you set `oLists` (please edit XPath in OP or show a more complete code)?; supposed to be a `NodeList` and not a single node. A nodelist can't show `.ChildNodes` and the recursive call uses the argument `oLists` with *both* types which should be a classical mismatch. So I doubt your function is working at all.  ... and remove the brackets around `... (listnode)` in the deletion code line: `listnode.ParentNode.RemoveChild listnode`.

Comment: @T.M. thanks for your comment. I hope the code I added does make it a bit more clear.  I removed the brackets around (listnode), unfortunately the behavior of the code did not change, the 'removed' tag is only empty, not removed ... :-(

Comment: posted an answer to your issue; feel free to accept by ticking the green checkmark and/or to upvote :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the `RemoveChild` syntax is correct:

> {NodeToDelete}.ParentNode.RemoveChild {NodeToDelete}

But let's repeat the xml structure and note that each text node (if existant) is regarded as a ChildNode of its parent (i.e. one hierarchy level deeper).

```
<Cdtr>                                   <!-- 0 documentElement                      -->
    <Nm>Name Creditor</Nm>               <!-- 1 ChildNode of Nm = 'Name Creditor'    -->
    <PstlAdr>                            <!-- 1 listNode.ParentNode.ParentNode       -->
        <Ctry>DE</Ctry>                  <!--   2 ChildNode of Ctry = 'DE'           -->
        <AdrLine>Street</AdrLine>        <!--   2 ChildNode of AdrLine[1] = 'Street' -->                   
        <AdrLine>                        <!--   2 listNode.ParentNode to be removed  -->
            <!-- NODETEXT ##REMOVE## --> <!--     3 ChildNode of AdrLine[2]          -->
        </AdrLine>
        </PstlAdr>
</Cdtr>
```

Diving down to bottom in xml hierarchy (assuming text values) via

```
    listnode.ParentNode.RemoveChild listnode
```

you are deleting the textual ChildNode of `AdrLine[2]` (level 3) which is the string `"##REMOVE##"`,
but not it container node `AdrLine[2]` (level 2). Therefore you are deleting only the dummy text.

Following your logic in function `RemoveOptionalEmptyTags()` as close as possible you'd have to code instead:

```
    listNode.ParentNode.ParentNode.RemoveChild listNode.ParentNode
```

addressing `PstlAdr` (=level 1) executing a deletion of its ChildNode `AdrLine[2]` (i.e. at level 2) which
automatically includes deletion of the dummy string "##REMOVE" at level 3.

**Related links**:

[XML Parse via VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53558110/xml-parse-vba-excel-function-trip-msxml2-domdocument/53559474#53559474)

[Obtain atrribute names from xml using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51887820/obtain-attribute-names-from-xml-using-vba/51919182#51919182)

Comment: Thank you soooooooo much for your help. It looks like it's working perfect. I'll still have to do some testing, but the first tests were very successful.

Comment: @Dietmar you wrote *"It looks like it's working perfect. I'll still have to do some testing..."*. Allow me the question if you could finish testing. - If my post solved your issue, feel free to accept by ticking the green checkmark; if helpful please upvote :-)