# VBA - What's The XPath Syntax To Get Tag Names

Tags: excel, vba, xpath, xmldom

I am trying to use a VBA macro to parse XML file. Given with the following structure:

```
  <bookstore>
  <book category="children">
    <title>Harry Potter</title>
    <author>J K. Rowling</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>29.99</price>
  </book>
  <book category="web">
    <title>Learning XML</title>
    <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>39.95</price>
  </book>
  </bookstore>
```

How can I enumerate the output with element tags with its corresponding values as shown below?

```
book | category | children
title | harry potter
author | J K. Rowling
...
```

My code as follows:

```
Set xmlFile = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlFile.Load (file)
Set qXML = xmlFile.SelectNodes("/bookstore")
For i = 0 To qXML.Length - 1
  Debug.Print CStr(qXML(i).Text)
Next i
```

Comment: You edited your question after I answered it. Did you read it already? Should answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, slight change for clarity but no change to the code at all. I tried to run with the solution you provided and it shows runtime error '91', object variable or with block variable not set.

Comment: I expected you code was running so far. But it seems its not like this. I used early binding in my project and so different code to instantiate the object. I edit my answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How to get Tag Names**

> *"What's the XPath syntax to get Tag Names?"*

Strictly speaking it's **(XML)DOM** syntax to to get `.Name` and/or `.NodeName` properties;
*XMLDOM (Document Object Model)* is a cross-platform and language-independent interface treating the document as a tree structure and allowing programmatic access to the tree.

You can use, however the special syntax of **XPath** expressions (like e.g. `"/bookstore/book/title"`) to address any logical part in the hierarchical xml document structure.

So a solution close to your OP would be:

```
Option Explicit             ' declaration head of your code module

Sub ExampleCall()
    Dim file As String: file = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\xml\bookstore.xml"
    Dim xmlFile As Object
    Set xmlFile = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    If xmlFile.Load(file) Then
        Dim qXML As Object
        Set qXML = xmlFile.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("book")
        Dim q As Object
        For Each q In qXML
            Dim cnt As Long: cnt = cnt + 1
            Debug.Print Format(cnt, "--- 000 ---")
            Debug.Print q.Attributes(0).Name, "|" & q.Attributes(0).Text
            Dim i As Long
            For i = 0 To q.ChildNodes.Length - 1
                Debug.Print q.ChildNodes(i).nodeName, "|" & q.ChildNodes(i).Text
            Next
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

**Results in VBE's immediate window**

```
--- 01 ---
category      |children
title         |Harry Potter
author        |J K. Rowling
year          |2005
price         |29.99
--- 02 ---
category      |web
title         |Learning XML
author        |Erik T. Ray
year          |2003
price         |39.95
```

**Side note**

As `Microsoft.XMLDOM` has been deprecated for years,
I'd prefer binding to ►`MSXML2` in the most current xml version `Microsoft XML,v6.0`, e.g. via

*I. LATE Binding (as in OP)*

```
    Dim xDoc As Object
    Set xDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
```

*II. EARLY Binding*

```
    Dim xDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60     ' *) whereas MSXML2.DOMDocument (=old version 3.0)
    Set xDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60  ' mind the missing point in digits
```

*Side note: OP uses the object variable `XMLFile` instead of `xDoc`*

*Note* that referencing `DOMDocument` without obvious versioning would bind internally to 3.0 by default
(the last stable version before 6.0, any other versions are deprecated).

**Further links**

- [Obtain attribute names from xml using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51887820/obtain-attribute-names-from-xml-using-vba/51919182#51919182)
- [XML Parse ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53558110/xml-parse-vba-excel-function-trip-msxml2-domdocument/53559474#53559474)

Comment: What if there's nested nodes?

Comment: @onlineCake ... then apply the code shown in the first link; the answer above tries to be as close as necessary to OP :-)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use early binding.
So in your project in the VBE add a reference (menu `tools/references`) to `Microsoft XML, v6.0`.

To determine the attribute and the values you can use this:

```vb
Dim xmlFile As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Set xmlFile = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

xmlFile.Load file

Dim qXML As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
Set qXML = xmlFile.SelectNodes("/bookstore/book")

Dim index As Long
For index = 0 To qXML.Length - 1
    Debug.Print qXML(index).SelectSingleNode("@category").Text
    Debug.Print qXML(index).SelectSingleNode("title").Text
    Debug.Print qXML(index).SelectSingleNode("author").Text
Next index
```

Comment: Friendly hint: The unchanged XPath expression from OP tries to address a *single* element, i.e. the possible `documentElement` and not a *NodeList*: try `Set qXML = xmlFile.SelectNodes("//book")` instead :-)

Comment: @T.M.: Thanks for you hint, but unfortunately I don't understand what you try to tell me. Would you be so kind and be more descriptive?

Comment: Look one hierarchy level deeper: Your code raises a `Run time error 91` *(Object variable or With block variable not set)* as your node selections  loop through not existing path queries within the `bookstore` object `qXML` (being also the documentElement/top level) and instead through the `book` elements the OP wants to analyze. Therefore the `bookstore` element cannot display sub nodes/attributes like  `@category`, `title` or `author`, only the subsequent `book` nodes :-)

Comment: Oh, darn, I missed that one. That must have happened during editing the answer. My test code ran here. Thanks for the info. I corrected that now.