# Struggling to pull information from XML file into excel using VBA

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I have been able to modify some code found on here to pull some data from an XML file but I am struggling to do this for one particular number, I am very new to XML files and cant figure out if what I am trying to pull is an Attribute/Node/Element. Below is the XML and the VBA I have so far.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<reel id="r1" protversion="17">
    <order number="81234">
        <job name="apples">
            <lengthunit>mm</lengthunit>
            <formatlength>570.0</formatlength>
            <formatwidth>1300.0</formatwidth>
        </job>
    </order>
</reel>
```

```
Function ReadFromXML2()

Set oXMLFile = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
XMLFileName = "E:\xml files\report1.xml"
oXMLFile.Load (XMLFileName)

Set Nodes_Attribute = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("reel")
For i = 0 To (Nodes_Attribute.Length - 1)
    Attributes = Nodes_Attribute(i).getAttribute("id")
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & i + 2).Value = Attributes
Next

Set TitleNodes = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/reel/order/job/formatlength/text()")
For i = 0 To (TitleNodes.Length - 1)
    Title = TitleNodes(i).NodeValue
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B" & i + 2).Value = Title
Next

End Function
```

The part I am struggling with is the order number, should I be using `getAttribute` or `NodeValue`? Whay I have so far works for getting the reel ID and formatlength.

Comment: Always use `Option Explicit` in the declaration head of code modules to force variable declarations and consider `MSXML2` instead of `Microsoft.XMLDOM` which has been deprecated for years. - This post might give you some further ideas: [What's the XPath syntax to get tag names (including attributes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65284905/vba-whats-the-xpath-syntax-to-get-tag-names/65289499#65289499)

Comment: Variables have been added properly now I have something working. Would this be as simple as changing ```Microsoft.XMLDOM``` to ```MSXML2``` in the code of will there different syntax completely?

Comment: Take the time to study the referred link(s). If you are using **late binding** as in OP (after dimensioning all your nodes etc `.. As Object` - you know objects have to be `Set`) write: Example: `Dim oXMLFile As Object` and `Set oXMLFile = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")

Comment: I have followed the links, I am attempting to use early binding, I have the put something together but I am now getting runtime error 91, object variable or with block variable not set, but am unsure what can cause that in this context

Comment: If you are sure that in the referred DocumentElement named `<reel id=".."> exists an attribute with name `id` you can write as follows: `Worksheets(2).Range("A" & LastRow + 1).Value = qXML(i).Attributes.getNamedItem("id").Text`
`

Comment: Thanks that sorted it, I was after attribute not node. Thanks. Is there a way to do this for several attributes without having to do ```Set qXML = xmlFile.SelectNodes("reel")``` each time? The data is in the same node, just one level down and is also an attribute (I think)

Comment: VBA knows a `With ...` ... `End With` structure by which you can abbreviate your references. Think, however that this has nothing to do with the original question - better to ask a new precise question. - Just try the further references I indicated in the mentioned link including a function to list attributes and showing recursive calls; if you found them helpful feel free to upvote them.

Comment: Thanks, I understand

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I used `getAttribute` but I was trying `"order number"` rather than just `"number"`